# Cannot access __doc__ from argparse without redefining it

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse, pylint, docstring

I have a module in which a define a module `__doc__` string (multiline) which I also want to use in my argparse usage.

So at first I defined it as

```
'''My
multiline
module
doc-string
'''
```

and used it in the following way

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=str(__doc__),
                                formatter_class=SmartFormatter)
```

(Note: left out the `SmartFormatter` class since it is not part of the problem).

When I now give the `-h` option it prints `None` where the doc-string should be.

I can solve it easily by defining the doc-string as follows:

```
__doc__ = '''My
multiline
module
doc-string
'''
```

But then pylint starts complaining:

```
<file.py>:<line>: [W0622(redefined-builtin), ] Redefining built-in '__doc__'
```

So now is my question how I can access the module doc-string without redefining `__doc__`, preferably I don't want to ignore the W0622 warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value for `__doc__` is `None` only if you didn't put that multi-line string as the *first statement of the file* (only comments can precede it).

Once you have the string object appear in the right location, `__doc__` will no longer be set to `None`, passing it to `argparse` will work and doesn't need to be re-defined.

Note that if you run your code with the [`-OO` command-line switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-oo), docstrings are dropped entirely.

As for disabling pylint warnings connected to a multi-line string, you can use a pair of comments to disable specific warnings for a few lines, then re-enabling them afterwards:

```py
# pylint: disable=W0622
__doc__ = """\
# ...
"""
# pylint: enable=W0622
```